# Displaying Page Title on index.php

Tags: posts, theme-development, title, homepage, wp-title

I have my posts page set as `index.php`, and on there I have my main heading (as I do on all pages).

I'm having trouble displaying the page's heading however. The page is called 'Blog' in WordPress, and has been specified as the posts page.

If I output the page heading with `wp_title('');`, I get the title of the page — 'Blog' — but with the site name after it (perhaps due to Yoast SEO plugin).

If I use `the_title()` then it gives me the title of the most recent blog post, even though I'm calling the function outside of the loop.

So I've had to resort to simple hardcoding `<h1>Blog</h1>` which is far from ideal.

Is there a way I can pull in the name of the page title dynamically but *just* the page title on it's own?

Comment: First off, `wp_title()` is used to display and hook into the `title` element of a document. Secondly, you should not be calling `the_title()` outside of the loop in the first place. Thirdly, please provide the source of `index.php`. `the_title()` works properly when used as directed ;-)

Comment: I can confirm that I encounter the same specific behaviour. I.e. Most recent blog post being used as page title instead of page title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strange. Outside the loop, the_title() *should* give you the current page name, *if* you really are on a page, and not viewing a specific post. If it gives post title instead, it may mean that you are somehow inside a loop. But if that were true, wp_title shouldn't show "Blog".

See if other options give the same result:

```
//the_title();
single_post_title();
echo $post->post_name; // I think this shows the url page name
```

Also check for is_page(). 
You might try the is_page('Blog') test.

```
if (is_page('blog')) {
echo 'Blog';
}
else {
the_title();
}
```

just to see what happens.

Comment: sorry for the massively belated response, `single_post_title();` seems to work, I'll go with that! ;)

Comment: Why not use the wp_query object? `$wp_query->query[pagename] `

Comment: `single_post_title();` produces the desired result.

Comment: single_post_title() definitely.

Answer (score 3):

It's correct that `the_title()` on blog page will return the most recent post's title and hence it can't be used.

When a page is set as a "posts page" from reading settings, WP calls `home.php` template file (or `index.php` if `home.php` doesn't exist) instead of `page.php` (see: [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)).

So, `is_page()` conditional won't work on blog page because it's not a page anymore.

The only way to output the actual page title is to use `single_post_title();`

`single_post_title()` is a part of the general-template.php file which clearly states that

> If we're on the blog page and that page is not the homepage or a single page that is designated as the homepage, use the container page's title.

You can review the code and comments here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L871

Answer (score 2):

```
$our_title = get_the_title( get_option('page_for_posts', true) );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: it works! ha ha

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if it is a blog page. Then if true use `single_post_title()` function.

```
( ( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) ? single_post_title() : the_title() );
```

Here it is considered that the blog page is not the front page.

`is_page()` won't work so far the blog page is not a page anymore in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the OP, but I'm hoping this helps others that came here looking for the same thing.

single_post_title() works for pages until you get to blog and category pages (and presumably product & tag pages in woocommerce)

So first simply check if it's a page, otherwise use the wp_title function

```
if (is_page()) {
    single_post_title();
} else {
    echo rtrim(wp_title('', false), '- ');
}
```

I did need to remove the site title from my settings, but I was manually adding it on either side of this function anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the post/page title for WordPress.

`get_the_title();` and `the_title();`

**How to use `get_the_title();`**

```php
<h1 class="entry-header text-primary fst-italic"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() ); ?></h1>
```

**How to use `the_title();`**

```php
the_title('<h1 class="entry-title  text-primary fst-italic">', '</h1>');
```

**What is difference between `get_the_title();` and `the_title();`?**
`the_title();` ill echo its value, but  `get_the_title();` does not echo (just returns the value).

This is the standard for WordPress functions: the functions that start with `the_` will echo what the corresponding function starting with `get_` returns. Other functions have a parameter to choose echo or not and others only return values.